# Is there any open source EGL test suite written in C/C++?

Tags: ios, egl

I am writing an [EGL implementation in C](https://github.com/davidandreoletti/libegl) and I would have liked to test it against some EGL test suites.

**Is there any open source EGL test suite written in C/C++ ?**

NOTE: Mesa Project has some EGL based demos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to  [Jon Leech (EGL & OpenGL Specification Editor / OpenGL ARB Ecosystem TSG Chair / Khronos API RegistrarEGL)](http://www.khronos.org/message_boards/showthread.php/5478-Any-conformance-kit-test-suite-for-EGL-API-testing)

> There is some minimal coverage testing in the client API-specific
>   tests, and the OpenKODE tests address use of multiple client APIs
>   together, to a limited degree. It's pretty hard to test EGL in
>   isolation since it really doesn't do anything without a client API to
>   operate on the resources it manages

Comment: I will then write my own set of tests and propose them to Mesa Project. They may be interested :)

Answer (score 1):

The Mesa developers are slowly adding EGL tests to Piglit, Mesa's testsuite. See this directory: http://cgit.freedesktop.org/piglit/tree/tests/egl/spec.